# Loop through the file and read all records

Tags: c, file, loops, struct, binary

I've got a file with multiple records. Each record contains a type(a binary value number), len(bin value again), and data(binary value whose length is len). The file contains multiple records. I want to print every record which contains it's own type, len, and data.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct file_s {
  int16_t type;
  int32_t length;
  // Assumption: Each record is 16 bits
  // For a record size of 32 bits, use int32_t*
  int16_t* data;
} file_s;

int main() {
  file_s file;
  FILE* f = fopen("file.bin","r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    perror("Error");
    return 1;
  }
  fread(&file.type, sizeof(file.type), 1, f);
  fread(&file.length, sizeof(file.length), 1, f);
  file.data = malloc(file.length * sizeof(*file.data));


  fread(file.data, sizeof(*file.data), file.length, f);
  fclose(f);
  // Process the data
  /* ... */
  free(file.data);
  return 0;
}
```

How do I loop through the file and print each record.

Comment: regarding: `file.data = malloc(file.length * sizeof(*file.data));`  this is multiplying the total length of the data portion of the record by the length of a pointer.  Probably not what you want.  However, the `file.length` contains the total number of bytes in the record for the data,  Suggest just using that value in the call to `malloc()`

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always check the third parameter with the returned value to assure the function was successful

Comment: regarding: `fread(&file.type, sizeof(file.type), 1, f);
  fread(&file.length, sizeof(file.length), 1, f);
  file.data = malloc(file.length * sizeof(*file.data));


  fread(file.data, sizeof(*file.data), file.length, f);`  this only reads the first record.  This code needs to be in a loop so all the records are read.  Within that loop, after reading all the parts of the record, then use `printf()` to print out the parts. Note: printing the individual data items may require another loop

Comment: regarding; `return 1;`  This would be better written as: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: for flexibility and ease of reading: it is best to separate the struct definition from a typedef for that struct

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to check the return value of fread every time, if the return value is smaller than expect, then check feof() to see if the end of the file reached. You can check the man page, by google "man fread" and "man feof". You can use a do while loop to loop through the file.

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
int feof(FILE *stream);
```

something like:

```
  while(1) {
      size_read = fread(&file.type, sizeof(file.type), 1, f);
      if(size_read!=1 || feof(f))
          break;
      fread(&file.length, sizeof(file.length), 1, f);
      //do the same check
      file.data = malloc(file.length * sizeof(*file.data));

      fread(file.data, sizeof(*file.data), file.length, f);
      //do the same check, remember to free the memory!
  }
```

Comment: You said to use a `do...while` loop, but your answer is using a `while` loop

Comment: Each pass through the loop is calling `malloc()`, but is not calling `free()` at the end of the loop, This means the allocated memory pointer: `file.data` is being overlayed in each loop.  Resulting in a unrecoverable memory leak on each iteration through the loop

Comment: You expect too much! The comment inside the code example clearly remind to free the memory!  The exact question is "How do I loop through the file and print each record."